Can we call England "a member nation" of the UK?

Overall, these data support the hypothesis that the UK will see an older population after half a century, which is the result of increases in the proportion of elderly people in each member nation.

I often see people calling a country "a member nation" if it is in an economic or military group like NATO or the UN, but I'm not sure about the UK case.


Yes, absolutely. It is acceptable and normal to say or write that Scotland, England, Wales and Northern Ireland are 'member nations' of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland. An alternative phrase might be 'constituent nations [of the UK]'.

Thank you! By the way, am I right to say that "...the UK will see an older population"? Emphasis on the bolded part.

Yes, but you should be aware that treating 'data' as a plural is increasing seen as old-fashioned and mainly done by people who wish that English were Latin.

I'll keep that in mind. With regard to the phrase "constituent nations", can we use it to describe member nations of the UN or NATO?

Aren't the projections themselves the hypothesis? How do they support the hypothesis?

Proofreading texts is off-topic but you have identified a specific problem. However  there is more than one inaccuracy in your written text. Here's a question for you: do we say normally say  "(the) increases proportion of people" or "an increase proportion of people“?

What @TimR said. I'd say the cited utterance is complete nonsense - the chart is a projection, not data (singular or plural). You can't meaningfully say a projection of future values "supports the hypothesis" that those projected future values will in fact come about.

I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about Geography/History and not about learning to speak English.

I wouldn't go so far as to say that the question is not about learning English. But the chart was not necessary to pose the question Can England be called a member nation of the UK?

Personally, I would not say "member nation". I'd say "countries that make up the United Kingdom are England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland. "member nations" is too identified with the UN and its constituent organizations and other organizations like ASEAN or NATO.

@TimR That's probably my fault.  I'd suggested (in other questions) using the "hypothesis" phrasing.  I agree it is a bit odd here.

Relating to the chart, I noticed that after I posted a question here, people tended to ask me about the context, which I hadn't thought was needed in the first place. That's why I did it just in case today.

@JamesK It seems that I have failed in my attempt to use the phrase...

@Mari-LouA My best guess of what you are implying is that I should write "increases in the proportions of...", or "an increase in the proportion of..."

@Lambie Is there any shorter phrase to refer to England, Wales, Scotland, or Northern Ireland?

Yes, I am :) "…which is the result of an increase in the proportion of elderly people" It's quite tricky that original sentence of yours. Interesting.

Yes, the countries of the UK: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countries_of_the_United_Kingdom

RE the comments referring to "elderly" as not a good term. Often in the collective imagination, the expression “elderly” will suggest a very old person who is frail, lacks physical strength, mental acuity and might need assistance. Nowadays, there are people aged 70 or older who are healthy, work out, lead active lives, still in employment and are fully autonomous.  And therefore a healthy 65-year-old might object to being referred to as elderly while they couldn't contest to be in the "aged 65 and over" category. They may not like it  but that's a different matter!

Overall, these data support the hypothesis that the countries of the UK will see an older population a half century from now as the result of increases in the percentage of seniors in each country.
OR
Overall, these data support the hypothesis that the countries of the UK (England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland) will see an older population a half century from now as the result of increases in the percentage of seniors in each country.
OR the countries can go under the chart, for example.
OR increase in the senior population percentages in each country
older population OR seniors
Yes, the countries of the UK: [countries of the United Kingdom]
1https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countries_of_the_United_Kingdom//which is the result of increases in the proportion of elderly people in each member nation=as the result of increases in the percentage of seniors + elderly people is not what is used in statistics, I think.
Personally, I would not use member nation. It's very identified with the UN system or things like ASEAN or NATO. [I am not saying it is an outright mistake.] However, elderly people is not a good term here.

Could you tell me what's wrong with "elderly people"?

https://www.prb.org/resources/fact-sheet-aging-in-the-united-states/ older Americans (those 65 or older) OR seniors. Elderly people is not a "professional" term and also does not mean those 65 or 60 and older. It's basically very old people. The OECD uses the term, others do not.

Senior population of the U.S. by state 2021 https://www.statista.com/statistics/736211/senior-population-of-the-us-by-state/

There are other sources like 1 and 2, which say otherwise.

The first one I already mentioned and the second is about defining elderly. The WHO says older people. NOT elderly.
